# Mocking Express Request with ts-mockito and Typescirpt

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, express, mocking, ts-mockito

Is it possible to mock the class Request from [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) using [ts-mockito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito) in typescript?

I tried the following

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express";  

const request = mock(Request);
const req: Request = instance(request);
```

but get an error on `req` stating: `Type 'Request' is missing the following properties from type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 73 more.`

Comment: Why do you want to mock a request? In general unit testing controllers is a bad idea, use something like Supertest.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd like to mock it precisely to test: so that inside my unit test I can pass a custom request (and response) object with dummy data. (btw, I don't have much experience in testing with typescript)

Comment: Again, unit testing controllers is a bad idea. So is mocking things you don't own!

Comment: I get your point: mocking external libraries is bad practice and should get avoided, when possible.

Since I may have misexplained myself, let me state my case further:
I am testing a function that gets triggered by an http request.
In order to do that, I have to pass it some custom arguments.
How would you pass custom arguments to that function, if not through a mock?

Comment: Again, you can either use something like Supertest to make requests. If you want to unit test some business logic the controller *uses* to handle the request, then test the service that provides it rather than the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request is an interface, so you should use this syntax:

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { mock, instance } from "ts-mockito";

const mockReq = mock<Request>();
const req = instance(mockReq);
```

Refer to the [ts-mockito documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito) for more.